# Question about the key in RC4

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, stream-cipher, rc4

I am planning to develop a more secure version of the RC4 algorithm. Since I´m not an encryption expert, I´ld like you to help me find answers to the following questions:

1. Does the value of the key array(T) have to be in this range `[0-255]`? If the answer is “yes”, could you please explain why?
2. Why did they use `s[t]` to generate the key and not the key array which is defined as `t` array in RC4?

   ```
   Output = S[(S[i] + S[j]) mod N];
   ```

Comment: *"i want to develop the RC4 algorithm to be more secure and i am not an expert in encryption"* Then don't, and use AES.

Comment: @fkraiem i am using RC4 for a reason which is very fast and i need that i my application

Comment: @lena, there are other fast ciphers you should prefer, e.g. Salsa20. Any modification to RC4 to actually make it secure will likely slow it down anyway. (That doesn't make this a bad question, though.)

Comment: @otus i would be glad if you suggest a list of stream or block cipher that is really fast and secure

Comment: @lena What's your target hardware? The relative performance of ciphers varies a lot between different CPUs.

Comment: "I am planning to develop a more secure version of the RC4 algorithm." You mean something like the Spritz cipher by Ron himself & all? And yes, that modification (if you can call it that, I'd rather call it a rewrite) does slow RC4 down quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

> Does the value of the key array(T) have to be in this range [0-255] if yes could you please specify why?

Yes. RC4 operates on bytes. There are 256 possible values for an 8 bit (1 byte) number, that range from 0 to 255. RC4 treats the key as an array of bytes, so every entry in the key array is by definition in the range 0 to 255.

> Why did they use s[t] to generate the key and not the key array which is defined as t array in RC4?

Without seeing the RC4 code you are referring to, it is hard to tell what you mean. $S$ is a keyed permutation (where the key is $T$) of the bytes in the range 0-255. The T array may not contain all bytes since it is generated by the user. So, in order to make it so that the values output as the keystream can be the entire range of byte values, they have to use $S$ instead of $T$.

> I want to develop the RC4 algorithm to be more secure

Bruce Schneier [once noted](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/08/new_attack_on_a_1.html): "*Again, I repeat the saying I've heard came from inside the NSA: 'Attacks always get better; they never get worse.'*"

The [most recent news on an RC4 attack](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/07/once-theoretical-crypto-attack-against-https-now-verges-on-practicality/) had this to say: "*The researchers said the only reliable countermeasure is to **stop using RC4 altogether**.*" (emphasis added)

A [number of attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) on RC4 have been published in recent years, and, they are only getting better. A lot of folks are removing RC4 completely from older systems.

**Important**
I want to point something out that I hope you don't skip over. Any sort of system designed these days should be designed in such a way that it is **not cipher specific**. In other words, if you really want your system to be "more secure", you should design it in such a way that it can theoretically support any cipher. That way, if one cipher gets broken, your system can easily adapt to a new one that isn't broken. If you are willing to share more details about your system, I think we can help you design it in such a way that this is possible. Likely that will mean using existing standards, or only slightly modifying a standard to fit your needs.

Comment: first thanks for replay this was really helpful regarding my system i want to create secure voice transmission system that will encrypt voice and send it so i need the system to be fast but at the same time very secure i will be grateful for any help or ideas

Comment: @lena, the best thing to do in security is to not reinvent the wheel and copy what others are doing. [Open Whisper Systems](https://whispersystems.org/) has built the RedPhone app for Android and the Signal app for iOS that does secure voice transmission. Check out their [source code](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/RedPhone) and their [documentation](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/RedPhone/wiki).

Comment: i am using udp protocol to transmit voice i guess they are using SIP and RTP so i do not guess there code will be applied in my system

Comment: @lena, maybe not, but you can learn from what they are doing and try to apply some of the general ideas. For example, how are symmetric keys established? Etc. The fact that they are using AES w/o issue, says you probably can too.

Comment: so do you think that the best algorithm that i can use to encrypt  voice is AES

Comment: @lena, "best" is hard for me to say given the amount of information I have. Given the fact that someone else is already using it for a similar application, I would say it has good potential. But, if you design your protocols such that they are not specific to one particular cipher, you can start with AES (not sure which mode OWS is using, but go with that too). Then you can switch things out if needed.

Comment: so you do not recommend using stream cipher to encrypt voice

Comment: AES is a block cipher that can be operated in streaming modes. I have no experience doing voice encryption in this type of application, so I can't really recommend a mode. That is why I suggest looking at what others are doing. A stream cipher like Salsa20 may work just fine too.

Comment: It looks like they are using AES in Counter mode, which basically turns AES into a stream cipher.

Answer (score 0):

> I am planning to develop a more secure version of the RC4 algorithm.
>   Since I´m not an encryption expert...

Never roll your own crypto, especially not if you are no expert in that topic. There are so many traps, starting from implementation bugs to side channel attacks. Simply use existing crypto libraries of secure algorithms like AES.